# Uploading big files PBIX into report server error uploading pbix files bigger than 200 MB

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am doing big upload to report server using Power Shell with standard procedure by Microsoft UploadLargeFiles.ps that sues APi 2.0. I get error uploading files bigger than 200 MB. I came up with this solution is it correct?

When dealing with large files, especially those exceeding the default maximum file size limit for uploads in Power BI Report Server, you might encounter issues using the `New-RsRestItem` command directly. In such cases, you can break down the process into smaller chunks or use other methods to upload the file. Below is an updated approach using the `Invoke-RestMethod` command to handle larger files:

1. **Install ReportingServicesTools Module**: If you haven't already installed the module, you can do so by running the following command in PowerShell:

   ```
   Install-Module -Name ReportingServicesTools
   ```
2. **Import Module**: After installing the module, import it into your PowerShell session:

   ```
   Import-Module ReportingServicesTools
   ```
3. **Connect to Report Server**: Connect to your Report Server using the `Connect-RsRestServer` command:

   ```
   $serverUrl = "http://your-report-server-url/ReportServer"
   Connect-RsRestServer -ServerUrl $serverUrl
   ```
4. **Upload Large .pbix file**: Use the `Invoke-RestMethod` command to upload the large `.pbix` file in chunks:

   ```
   $filePath = "C:\Path\To\Your\File.pbix"
   $targetFolder = "/Your/Target/Folder"  # Specify the folder path on the Report Server

   # Read the file as a byte array
   $fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)

   # Define chunk size (adjust as needed)
   $chunkSize = 10MB

   # Initialize variables
   $start = 0
   $end = $chunkSize - 1
   $index = 1

   # Upload file in chunks
   while ($start -lt $fileBytes.Length) {
       $chunk = $fileBytes[$start..$end]

       # Upload chunk
       $url = "$serverUrl/api/v2.0/PowerBIReports?name=$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePath))&overwrite=true&folder=$targetFolder&chunkindex=$index"
       Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType "application/octet-stream" -Body $chunk

       # Update variables for next chunk
       $start += $chunkSize
       $end = [math]::Min($start + $chunkSize - 1, $fileBytes.Length - 1)
       $index++
   }
   ```

Replace `"http://your-report-server-url/ReportServer"` with the URL of your Report Server, `"C:\Path\To\Your\File.pbix"` with the local path to your `.pbix` file, and `"/Your/Target/Folder"` with the target folder path on the Report Server.

This script reads the `.pbix` file as a byte array and uploads it to the Report Server in chunks. Adjust the `$chunkSize` variable as needed based on your requirements and server limitations.

error uploading pbix files bigger than 200 MB